# Sphinx vs. Pydoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydoc

I'm deciding whether to use Sphinx or Pydoc for documenting a large existent project. Which one should I choose? Which one perform better on given conditions? Which one is faster to configure a run over a project?

Comment: Perhaps a more feature oriented question could be valid. For example pdoc used markdown while sphinx uses restructuredtext.